# Copy Info from Sub-Form to Form based on input in two text boxes

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm making a form that I can put input utility bills and their information into. Every utility bill is specific to a certain meter, and a lot of this info will be the same as the previous month's info that was put in. I have boxes on the form where they can input the type of utility it is, and the meter number, and then based on that input I have a subform show all the previous utility bills and info from that meter. I'm trying to find a way to code it so that all duplicate information will automatically be filled in when the utility type and meter number is put in, because it's a pain to put in the previous reading and date when it's already been put in. My question is, is there a way to grab this information from the subform and put it into the form?

This is the code I have so far:

```
    Private Sub MeterID_AfterUpdate()
Dim Ut As String
Dim Metid As Integer
Dim Month As Integer
Dim Year As Integer
Dim PrevReading As Double
Dim Criteria As String
Ut = Me.Utility
Metid = Me.MeterID
Month = DLookup("Mon", "qryPhyUtl", "Utility=""" & Ut & """ AND " & _
               "MeterID= """ & Metid & """")
Year = DLookup("Yr", "qryPhyUtl", "Utility=""" & Ut & """ AND " & _
               "MeterID= """ & Metid & """")
If Month = 12 Then
    Month = 1
    Year = Year + 1
Else
    Month = Month + 1
End If
PrevReading = DLookup("CurReading", "qryPhyUtl", "Mon", "qryPhyUtl", "Utility=""" & Ut & """ AND " & _
           "MeterID= """ & Metid & """")
Me.Mon = Month
Me.Yr = Year
Me.PreReading = PrevReading
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the subform's query in descending order.

In your code, use the RecordsetClone property of the subform to reference any field you need in the first row, and apply to the new record.

Very roughly:

```
Dim rs as recordset

Set rs=me!mySubform.form.RecordsetClone: With rs
    If not .EOF then
        PrevReading = !CurrentReading
        (etc)
    End If
.close: End With
Set rs=nothing
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your post, it really helped and actually pointed me in a much simpler direction. I just grabbed values straight from the subform and made the form equal them. The only problem I'm running into now is that the subform loads at the same time as the vba is supposed to be grabbing these values from it, and so the vba runs before the subform loads. However if I rerun it after the subform is loaded, it works perfectly. Any ideas on how to make the vba wait until the subform has loaded?